# Failed to send mail on Rails but works on simple ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

The following code can send mails perfectly,

But not works on Rails.

```
content = "sample_content"
smtp = Net::SMTP.new("mail.#{@domain}", 25 )
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start( @domain, @user_name, @passwd, :login) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message content, @sender, [@receiver]
end
```

### Here's my settings on development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
    :address        => "mail.#{ENV['domain']}",
    :domain         => ENV['domain'],
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name      => 'ENV["username"]',
    :password       => 'ENV["passwd"]',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

### Error message on console

```
Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing in the same username & password? Also, the domains seem different...

Comment: has rails been run from the same user as the script?

Comment: First try for hard code in your development.rb then go for environment variables.

Comment: Why do you need to send an email in Rails in a non-standard way? Why not you just a default Rails Mailer (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you are using a different account in the `from` in your emails than the account that you are using in your `smtp_settings`

To have this clearer:

Imagine that your smtp_settings are

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
    :address        => "mail.#{ENV['domain']}",
    :domain         => ENV['domain'],
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name      => 'me@example.com',  ######## this is the important part of the explanation
    :password       => 'ENV['passwd']',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

and then in your mail class:

```
def greet
  mail(from: 'you@example.com', and: 'other params')
end
```

Then the mail server will answer with that.

It is possible to setup you email server so that one account can send emails as a different one.

If this is not possible for you, may be you can put all you mail config into an yml file and load it on the fly before sending the emails.

Having different mail classes subclassing ActionMailer::Base is another option too.